# Python pandas to sql with no column names

Tags: python, sql, pandas

**TL;DR**

- I'm having issues loading df.to_sql
- column names are not defined/available in the raw file header
- error message seems to be because to_sql is trying to match the column index values in df to the table (which do not exist)
- looking for way to upload df when there are no column names

---

I have a file where the data begins at row 60. It has no headers and is pipe separated. Extract below:

[image: Data extract]

I load the data into a dataframe using this:

```
df_idx_file = pd.read_csv(str_stg_Full_FilepathName,compression='zip',sep='|',skiprows=59, header=None)
```

Which looks like this as a variable:

[image: Variable dataframe]

And I am trying to load it into my SQL Server table like this:

```
# Create SQL engine parameter
sql_cn_Params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(cn_ConnectionString)
# Create engine
sql_Engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(sql_cn_Params))
# Upload dataframe to DB
df_idx_file.to_sql('r_idx', con=sql_Engine, if_exists='append')
```

*(I've tested the engine and connection string on a basic SELECT query and it works fine.)*

When I execute the above code I get the below error:
[image: Error]

And it's like that for all 54 columns.

In terms of the table design/structure:

- There is an additional Identity column (at the beginning)
- All other data structures were created to match the raw file
- But I can see the dataframe seems to load the dates as a number, rather than a date. Could this cause me a problem down the line?

So I would like to know if there is any way to upload from the dataframe (that has no specified column names) into the SQL table (which does have column names), but the order/index of columns are the same.

Comment: Why not add column names to the dataframe after importing and then try uploading? ` my_columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
df.columns = my_columns`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to maintain the columns, but if there is no other way?